# Keeping users signed in no matter what using Firebase and Ionic

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I'm trying to keep users logged into my Ionic 3 application through firebase. When the user closes the app and reopens it, they are greeted with the login screen and are prompted to login again. This is harmful for the user experience. 
I have pasted this inside my login function, it's taken straight from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

However, this hasn't worked for me. Is there another way to do this? Or perhaps another way to keep users signed into the app no matter what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to use the firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged() inside your ionViewPageLoad() or constructor method not inside any function because you want to check the state before page loads or enters and you can even use this in your main component(app component) so that whenever the app loads it checks it right there and set the root page accordingly for you.

You probably want the user to be navigated to the screen which the user is taken after login (somewhat like homepage or so) so when you get the user object from firebase that means the user is logged in and you should navigate to that page not the LoginPage again so it should be something like this:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot('XyzPage'); //to the page where user navigates after login
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage); // to the login page as user is not logged in
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried to load this code into both the app.component and the LoginPage with ionViewDidLoad() and both times I get an error with the NavCtrl, do you know a way around this? `core.es5.js:1084 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'navCtrl' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'navCtrl' of undefined`

Comment: Just before the firebase.auth() function declare let self=this and then try to access navCtrl as self.navCtrl then check if it's still undefined

Comment: Thank you! That works wonderfully now. I'm still new to Ionic and Firebase.

Comment: Note that you could use `es6` and instead of `let self=this` you could simply write your func with `onAuthStateChanged((user) => {`. This will use the right `this` context.